# How to load a downloaded h5 model in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am receiving the following error when trying to load a model that was downloaded from github and am getting the following error
`SavedModel file does not exist at: modelname/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`.

I used `tf.keras.models.load_model` but I believe that is used if the model was already saved. Are there methods to load in an external model that was not previously saved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a complete path(including file name) of your model to the function.

```
my_model = keras.models.load_model("path/to/my_h5_model.h5")
```

this fuction supports both string and python [Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says it is not able to find the `model` to load it, you can try changing the model name if you are saving it again, If you are using make sure you follow the proper folder structure and methods as mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize) document.